# youtube-v3-api setModerationStatus is not changing it from rejected to published

Tags: youtube-data-api

This [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/setModerationStatus) is not functioning as it is supposed to according to the Youtube API documentation.

I can set the moderationStatus as **published**

and then set the moderationStatus as **rejected** without any problems

but I **can't** change it back from rejected to anything else, it always returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.comment",
    "reason": "processingFailure",
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid."
 }
}
```

I get the same error from Google's official PHP library, from youtube API console and CURL.

UPDATE - HTTP request example:

```
POST /youtube/v3/comments/setModerationStatus?id=UgyxQJSR-xEMmAWJDjZ4AaABAg&moderationStatus=published HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Length: 0
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json

HTTP/1.1 400
status: 400
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
vary: Origin
vary: X-Origin
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-encoding: gzip
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Vary,X-Google-GFE-Backend-Request-Cost
date: Thu, 31 May 2018 15:54:36 GMT
expires: Thu, 31 May 2018 15:54:36 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
content-length: 245
server: GSE
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
```

Comment: Please provide your HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, i've created an issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79958369

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't an answer to the question. It would have been better posted as a comment to the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for help on how to answer a question.